# Doctrine Batch insert - entity manager clear

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to insert 10 000 rows to database with batch processing.
In first step I need select some objects from databse, then interate these objects and for each of them persist another object to database.
Here is code example:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $products = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Product')->findAll(); // return 10 000 products
    $category = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Category')->find(1);
    $batchsize = 100;
    foreach ($products as $i => $product) {
        $entity = new TestEntity();
        $entity->setCategory($category);
        $entity->setProduct($product); // MyEntity And Product is OneToOne Mapping with foreign key in MyEntity
        $em->persist($entity);
        if ($i % $batchsize === 0) {
            $em->flush();
            $em->clear();
        }
    }
    $em->flush();
    $em->clear();
```

It returns this error:

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'Handel\GeneratorBundle\Entity\GenAdgroup#product' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity
```

I think problem is in `clear()`, that remove all objects in memory including $`products` and $`category`.

If I use `cascade={"persist"}` in association, doctrine insert new category row in db.

After some attempts I made some dirty entity errors.

Am I doing sometihng wrong? What is solution and best practice for this job?
Thanks a lot for answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

solution is just to clear only those objects that are changing/creating. Those one that are constant should be left within EntityManager.

Like this

```
$em->clear(TestEntity::class);
$em->clear(...);
```

If you left clear without param it will detach all objects that are current under entity manager. Meaning that if you try to reuse them it will throw error as you get. For instance unique filed will be duplicated and trow that error.

Answer (score 0):

After calling

```
$em->clear();
```

Category object becomes unpersisted. 
You can try calling $em->merge($category) method on it. But probably the most guaranteed way is to fetch it again.

```
    if ($i % $batchsize === 0) {
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear();
        $category = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Category')->find(1);
    }
```

Comment: But I does not want to persist cateogry, I have allready stored id and I only read it and set as a foreign key.

Comment: Persist is not going to work as you expect.  Merge might but the best bet is $category = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Category')->find(1);

Comment: And consider using getReference instead of find if you don't need the complete entuty.

Comment: You can read here, that when you fetch the object from the database - it becomes managed automatically. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#updating-an-object

By persisting it like this ($em->persist($category), it won't be added to the database as a new enitity (with new ID).

I have edited the answer, as it's really the best guaranteed way to have the managed Category object is to just simply fetch it again.

Comment: Almost.  But you need to have $category = $em... Otherwise the original now un-managed object will be used.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for noticing it. What a shame for missing it

Comment: Ok.
Fetch category in every batch loop is not problem. Thanks for answer.
But now there is main problem with $products, because they are cleared as well.